# primefaces Data table with expandable rows + editable expansion

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using Primefaces (version 3.4) dataTable with expandable rows. It is working fine.
Now I want to edit the expansion and to save the edit.

I tried it as follows but not working..

```
 <p:rowExpansion>
    <p:panelGrid>       
     <p:row>
        <p:column>
          <h:outputText value="GiveText" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column >
          <p:inputTextarea id="editText" value="#{myBean.myText}"
          counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." counter="countDisplay"/>
          <br />
          <h:outputText id="countDisplay" />        
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
      <p:column colspan="2">
        <p:commandButton value="Add Text" type="submit" ajax="true" 
                  action="#{myBean.addTextAction}" process="editText" update="table"/>                                                                          
      </p:column>
    </p:row>                                    
    </p:panelGrid>              
    </p:rowExpansion>
```

myBean.addTextAction is as follows

```
public void addTextAction(){
   MyClass myClassObj =new MyClass();
   if(!myText.isEmpty()){
   myClassObj.setText(myText);
   }
   else{
   myClassObj.setText(null);
   }
}
```

how can I achieve it?..

Comment: How does your myBean.addTextAction looks like? Can you post that methode?

Comment: Always ,Always , Always post your backbean code.

Comment: You have posted the method what about remaing code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I put the Table in a form.
Now it is working fine.